# In C++ Ogre or OpenGL, how to do rendering once and get multiple images with objects at different pose?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, render, ogre

Let's say I want to render a video of one asteroid rotating around its planet.  One straightforward way is to place the asteroid at different pose around the planet and render each time to get one image. If the video consists of 100 images, then I have to render 100 times for each image. This looks not very efficient.

However, since I already know all the poses the asteroid could be. I want to get all the pictures in one-pass-rendering, i.e. in each picture, the asteroid is in different location relative to the planet. Is there a way to render once and get all the pictures by taking advantage of GPU computation?

I guess this is doable if we do this in CUDA, but I'm wondering if there is a way in Ogre? Or dive into OpenGL if neccessary.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Even though your question is concrete, could you share a snipped of the code you tried/tested so far? Doing so will increase to get an answer quickly.

Comment: You could use a big texture and render different things in different sectors of that texture. Now, after this "pre-calculation" you could select the sector to blit into the window. But the whole scene should be really complex to take advantage with this approach.

Comment: Are you asking about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: Also, isn't your question *really* about how to "keep the planet static"? That is, how to effectively render the static planet into 4 images at the same time?

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for reminding. I removed the  ES tag. I think "render the static planet into 4 images at the same time" is more relevant to render to multiple targets. But in my case, the asteroid might be the trickest part.

Comment: There is not really much you can do about the asteroid because almost everything in the pipeline will be different for the different frames. The only thing that stays constant is the planet and you could try to take advantage of that. If that can succeed depends on the complexity of your planet rendering (if it is very cheap, it is unlikely to get a performance boost).

Comment: You could ofcourse use [Multiple Cameras](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultipleCameras.html) and render the objects on different Layers so you render the planet only once and then the other objects with different cameras and render layers

Comment: @derHugo, this sounds promising! Could you give any more hints about how to do this in OpenGL or Ogre?

Comment: @JesusTom: "*I have to render 100 times for each image*" No, you would have to render 100 times to get the *video*, not to get each image. "*This looks not very efficient.*" What is the basis for this conclusion? This is how pretty much *every* graphics program does it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess other graphics do because in animation there is also physics and until computing the physics of each frame, it does not know the poses of objects.
In my case, I already know all the poses of object I want to render. So I'm wondering if there is a way to render them all once.

Comment: @JesusTom: What performance do you think would be lost if you couldn't "render them all [at] once?" Is the GPU sitting idle under applications that render a lot of stuff? That's what I don't understand; what is the point of this? How would what you're talking about make rendering faster? And would any such improvement actually be meaningful in some way?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because in my case, my GPU is always hungry. I have a GPU with large RAM but when rendering one image, it just takes a little RAM. So there might be potential to take advantage of GPU's parallelism to render more at once. Also I have really lots of images to render, so I care a lot about this difference. It's not for some games or animation.

Comment: @JesusTom: "*Because in my case, my GPU is always hungry.*" Then send more work and keep it fed. If you're not beholden to presenting an image, there's no reason why you can't just constantly send stuff for the GPU to do. A GPU only starves when the CPU stops telling it what to do.